# ionic 2 <ion-footer> not scrolling when keyboard is open in ios

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have one issue in ionic2(IOS). when my keyboard is open then `<ion-footer>` not scroll to up in ios only. i'm used `Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` for disable scroll. but if i remove it then work good. any solution without remove `Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` scroll `<ion-footer>`.??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5YNG.png)